# Finding mean of normal distribution given probability between two endpoints

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, inverse, means

There is a well-known method for finding the mean of a normal distribution (given its variance) given the probability below a certain endpoint by normalizing the distribution:
$$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
$$P(X<a) = 0.8$$
$$P(Z<\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.8$$
$$\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma} = 0.841...$$
after which, provided $\sigma$ and $a$, one can solve for $\mu$.

---

However, what if one is given **two** endpoints, between which the probability lies?
$$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
$$P(a<X<b) = 0.8$$
$$P(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.8$$
$$P(Z<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) - P(Z <\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.8$$

How would I continue to find the mean $\mu$ of this distribution provided the values of $\sigma$, $a$, and $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write
$$
F(\mu):=\textstyle P(Z<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) - P(Z <\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})=\Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) - \Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})\,.
$$
The derivative of this w.r.t. $\mu$ is
$$
F'(\mu)=\frac{\Phi'(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}) - \Phi'(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma})}{\sigma}
$$
When $\mu<a<b$ then $F'(\mu)>0\,$ and when $a<b<\mu$ then $F'(\mu)<0$.

This means that the equation $F(\mu)=c$ has typically two solutions $\mu$. Newton-Raphson should be stable enough to find them based on reasonable starting values.